# py -m ensurepip doesn't install the latest version of pip (instead of 23.3, it installed 21.1)

Tags: python, pip, version, ensurepip

I am stuck here as I have python 3.9 installed but it came with 21.1.3 pip. I would like to upgrade my pip but it keeps saying 21.1.3 version is the latest which is not true. I uninstalled my pip and then reinstalled it using py -m ensurepip but still, it installed pip-21.1.3 for me but not 23.3 the latest.

Anyone has encountered the same problem?

cheers!

[image]

Comment: `ensurepip` only uses local installation data to provide a working (not necessarily newest) pip. Use `py -m pip install --upgrade pip` then to retrieve newest version from internet.

Comment: thank you Michael. I actually used py -m pip install --upgrade pip before I tried ensurepip. The same result still...

Comment: So better ask a question why `py -m pip...` (with output and maybe other useful information) didn't work because `ensurepip` behaved as expected.

Comment: It worked on Python 3.12.0rc3